# Unable to hit url by HttpPOST in actionable cards in microsoft teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to make a [Actionable Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/) for Microsoft Teams with an [ActionCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/card-reference#actioncard-action).

I want to hit a url by `HttpPost`.  When I hit the url, I got the error message:

```
Failed to send

There was a problem submitting your changes. Try again in a minute.
```

I followed Microsoft's documentation and according to the documentation my code is right.  I am very confuse why this error is coming up.

This is the ActionCard I'm using:

```
{
    "@type": "ActionCard",
    "name": "Selector",
    "inputs": [{
        "@type": "MultichoiceInput",
        "id": "list",
        "title": "Select a status",
        "isMultiSelect": "false",
        "style": "expanded",
        "choices": [{
                "display": "In Progress",
                "value": "1"
            },
            {
                "display": "Active",
                "value": "2"
            },
            {
                "display": "Closed",
                "value": "3"
            }
        ]
    }],
    "actions": [{
        "@type": "HttpPOST",
        "name": "Save",

        "body": "value={{list.value}}",
        "target": "https://www.google.com"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Teams is surfacing an error because you're call resulted in an error.

Your code looks fine but your target URL (Google.com) isn't valid. You can't make an POST request to https://www.google.com. Attempting to do so results in a `Error 405 (Method Not Allowed)`.

Making an `HttpPOST` requires a target that is willing to accept it and return some type of `2xx Success` response. Typically it will be `200 OK` but some APIs get more granular with their responses (`201 Created`, `202 Accepted`, etc.).

Comment: I tried this url "target": "https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?cow"   but showing me same error

Comment: That API isn't going to work either. First it uses a `GET` rather than `POST` and second you're not calling it correctly. The correct URI looks like this: `https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key={api-key}&q={search-string}`.